# redis shows empty set for lrange list

Tags: redis

I'm seeing a strange behavior in `redis` when using the `lrange` command.

I have a list called "test" with 10000000 values. When I ask for 100 rows starting at 99999 it returns an empty set?!

Any ideas why?

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "test"
127.0.0.1:6379> type test
list
127.0.0.1:6379> llen test
(integer) 10000000
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange test 99999 100
(empty list or set)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the arguments - it's not like similar commands in other languages.

The stop value is not "how many rows from 'start' should I pull", but rather, "which row should I stop at".

so `lrange test 99999 100` meant "start at 99999 end at 100" which makes no sense.

I would have to do `lrange test 99999 100099`.